# Is it possible to display the return value in a tooltip by hovering over a method in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I get text in different languages from a public class "Translations". Within the class, there is a field with an array that contains the text in the different languages:

```
public class Translations
{
    private static readonly string[,] _text = new string[,] {
        {"English text",
        "German text"},

        {"English text 2",
        "German text 2"},
    };
    
    public static string GetGuiText(int textIndex, int languageIndex) => _text[textIndex, languageIndex];
}
```

I get the text e. g. with `Translations.GetGuiText(1, 1)`
what results in "German text 2".
My problem is, when I hover over `Translations.GetGuiText(1, 1)` in Visual Studio 2022, I do not see, what text it is, but only the general information. So, when I am in a different file and see something like `text = Translations.GetGuiText(1, 1);`, I do not knkow what the text really is and I have to navigate to my translations file. Is there a possibility to see the real text in a tooltip when hovering over `GetGuiText(1, 1)`?

Comment: While debugging, after executing the method, you can hover over `text` to see the newly-assigned value. I wouldn't expect just hovering over a method to execute it - that would invite any number of problems (and in many cases it would be infeasible - your situation has constant arguments, but what if they were variables)?

Comment: I understand the problems and also that in many cases it wouldn't be feasible, but in my case executing the method is feasible. I did not really believe there is a solution, but wanted to be sure, because it is so often "press F12 > go to index x > navigate back". Anyway, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging is the only solution to this method, and usually the values we can see in the container are the results of the code being compiled. You only need to set a breakpoint under Translations.GetGuiText(1, 1) and then debug. At this time, hover the mouse over Translations.GetGuiText(1, 1) to see its content.

Never expect the code before compilation to provide you with the functionality after the code is compiled.

However, if it is based on relatively small data, corresponding methods can be created separately, as shown below:

```
    public static string GetGuiTextEnglish() => _text[0, 0];

    public static string GetGuiTextGerman() => _text[0, 1];

    public static string GetGuiTextEnglish1() => _text[1, 0];

    public static string GetGuiTextGerman2() => _text[1, 1];
```